# TabrisJs working with Upnp

Tags: javascript, node.js, upnp, tabris, tabris-js

Upnp looks harder to work with in TabrisJs.
It supports node packages to a large extent, but I am finding a tough time working with Upnp.

In package.json I got [node-upnp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-upnp-client)

```
"dependencies": {
    "tabris": "^2.0.0-rc2",
    "moment": "~2.8.4",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.2.5",
    "android-versions": "1.1.0", 
    "node-mind": "1.0.1",
    "node-ssdp": "3.2.1",
    "node-upnp-client" : "0.0.2",
    "node-ssdp-lite": "0.2.0"
  },
```

In app js I have initialized it as

```
const upnpClient = require('node-upnp-client');
const cli = new upnpClient();
console.log(cli.searchDevices());
```

I am getting

```
Could not load main module: 
Reference error: process is not defined
```

Now its pointing to this line first `var path = process.env.SSDP_COV ? './lib-cov/' : './lib/'`, in `node-ssdp/index.js`, [^](https://github.com/diversario/node-ssdp/blob/master/index.js)

I dont know why but it works perfectly in the CLI but not in the app.

Requiring `node-ssdp` alone says it can't load `dgram`, even though it is [part of Node](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html)

And I am not sure if the `dgram` package is available separately.

How to rectify these error and get Upnp support in tabrisJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabris.js uses a Node.js compatible module system to allow using modules hosted on npm in your app. However, it does not implement most of the [Node.js APIs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/).

Some basic APIs like [Timer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/timers.html) and [Console](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/console.html) are available. In addition to that, a small subset of the Node APIs is supported by the [tabris-js-node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabris-js-node). Unfortunately, the network APIs of Node.js (dgram is one of them) are not implemented in Tabris.js.

This rules out npm plugins that build on these APIs. You'd have to implement this functionality on top of Tabris APIs such as [`fetch` or `websockets`](https://tabrisjs.com/documentation/latest/w3c-api.html#fetch).

Comment: That is something to work on. It would be rough journey though.